# Can't locate object method

Tags: perl, oop

I'm still in the process of learning the basic fundamentals of OO Perl.
I have created a package called BigBrother.pm with a basic constructor.

```
package BigBrother;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $self = {
        datacenter => $args->{datacenter},
        testname   => $args->{testname},
        hostname   => $args->{hostname},
        ipaddress  => $args->{ipaddress},
        eventtime  => $args->{eventtime},
        responsetime  => $args->{responsetime},
        error         => $args->{error} || ''
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}
```

I also created two methods: one that records the time before the event started and the other to record the time when the event stopped.

```
sub setTimer {
my $self = shift;
my $start = `date +%s.%N`;
$self->{startTimer} = $start->startTimer;
}

sub endTimer {
my $self = shift;
my $end = `date +%s.%N`;
return $self->{endTimer} = $end->endTimer;
}
1;
```

In my perl executable script, I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use Xymon::Plugin::Server::Hosts;
use lib "/usr/lib/xymon/server/ext";
use BigBrother;

BEGIN {
$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}= "/usr/lib/xymon/server/ext/";
}

my $bigbro = new BigBrother;
my $ret = $bigbro->setTimer;
```

But I'm getting the following error when I run the script:

```
# ./a.pl
Can't locate object method "startTimer" via package "1422368625.492495754
" (perhaps you forgot to load "1422368625.492495754
"?) at /usr/lib/xymon/server/ext/BigBrother.pm line 22.
```

This is line 22 of BigBrother.pm

```
 sub setTimer {
 20     my $self = shift;
 21     my $start = `date +%s.%N`;
 22     $self->{startTimer} = $start->startTimer;
 23 }
 24
 25 sub endTimer {
 26     my $self = shift;
 27     my $end = `date +%s.%N`;
 28     $self->{endTimer} = $end->endTimer;
 29 }
```

Obviously, I'm missing something. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

```
my $start = `date +%s.%N`;
```

The above stores a string (not an object) in `$start`. Change your sub to:

```
sub setTimer {
    my $self = shift;
    my $start = `date +%s.%N`;
    $self->{startTimer} = $start;
}

sub endTimer {
    my $self = shift;
    my $end = `date +%s.%N`;
    return $self->{endTimer} = $end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the two relevant lines:

```
21     my $start = `date +%s.%N`;
22     $self->{startTimer} = $start->startTimer;
```

You call `date` and store its output as string in scalar variable `$start`. Then you try to run the method `startTimer` on this non-object. This doesn't work out what is perfectly correct.

Do you have defined a `startTimer` method somewhere or do you some module that should provide it?